# chef error on centos 5.3

Tags: yum, chef

I am trying to configure chef on my CentOS sever...
sudo chef-solo -c ~/solo.rb -j ~/chef.json -r http://s3.amazonaws.com/chef-solo/bootstrap-latest.tar.gz

should install basic things....

but Iam receiving

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.7.5/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:50:in `action_install': No version
>   specified, and no candidate version
>   available

Searched for it on google and found this

> Yum provider seems broken

at tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-212

and it says got fixed in version 0.5.6

my chef version is 0.7.5 and Iam still facing the problem......

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Chef (0.7.14) has RPMs packaged through a community contribution. The [RPM installation via yum](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Installation+on+RHEL+and+CentOS+5+with+RPMs) will install all the dependencies and start up a server (or set up a client) automatically.